# How to solve 'set_pos()' unsupported for codec error in pygame?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I had made a project where I require 'set_pos()' function in my python script, but it gives an error of unsupported in codec.

Here is my code:

```
#code 

fast_forward_icon= tk.PhotoImage(file=__file__+ '/../images/JPEG, PNG/icons/fast_forward.png')
def fast_forward(event=None):
    def func():
        global progressbar_music
        current_song_Length = mixer.music.get_pos()//1000
        print(current_song_Length)
        # mixer.music.pause()
        f= current_song_Length+10
        mixer.music.set_pos(f)
        progressbar_music['value']=f
        # mixer.music.progressbar_music(seconds=current_song_Length+10)
        progressbar_music_starttime.configure(text='{}'.format(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=f))))
        progressbar_music.after(2,func)
    func()

fastForwardBtn = Button(root, bg='#310A3D', image=fast_forward_icon, command=fast_forward)
```

My error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 1702, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 746, in callit
> func(*args)   File "e:/python projects/MUSIC PLAYER/music_player.py", line 346, in func
> mixer.music.set_pos(f) pygame.error: set_pos unsupported for this codec

Comment: Try converting the sound file to a different type

Comment: `WAV` audio format should easily support setting position, some other formats like yours may not support setting to random position, hence you need to convert to `WAV`.

Comment: Sir, how can I convert mp3 to wav audio format in the code and export it in python queue without saving in disk?

Comment: @SDBDARKNINJA Implemented [my solution/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64644287/941531) for converting MP3 to WAV, or even any audio format to any other format.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use `pydub` library, install it one time through `python -m pip install pydub`. Next function that I wrote accepts bytes of MP3 (or any other audio format) and returns WAV bytes (or any other format signified by `format = '...'` argument), function doesn't use any file system (all is done in-memory).

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64633496#main.py)

```
# Needs: python -m pip install pydub
# Convert
def conv_aud(data, format = 'wav'):
    import pydub, io
    inp, out = io.BytesIO(data), io.BytesIO()
    pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(inp).export(out, format = format)
    return out.getvalue()
# Test
with open('test.mp3', 'rb') as f:
    print(conv_aud(f.read())[:32].hex().upper())
```

Output for my `test.mp3`:

```
5249464624D0110357415645666D7420100000000100020044AC000010B10200
```

Another way is to use FFMpeg like in my next solution.

I wrote next function `conv_aud()` that is able to convert any audio format to any other format, in fact it is able to convert video also.

By default if format is not provided it converts MP3 to WAV.

Function uses [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), install it one time. Also if it is located inside dir that is not in PATH system variable then you should provide argument `ffmpeg = 'c:/path/to/ffmpeg.exe'` to function `conv_aud()`.

Function accepts either bytes data of input audio or str path to input file or any file-like object opened for reading. Also it accepts `ifmt` argument for input format string like `'mp3'` and/or accepts `ofmt` argument for output format string like `'wav'`.

Function returns bytes data of WAV.

Function uses intermediate temporary directory and files that are deleted on exit. Also function prints error output from FFMpeg in case of error. If there is error then function is silent, prints nothing.

At the end of code there is `test()` function to test different ways of calling function using `test.mp3` file as input.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64633496var2#main.py)

```
# Converts any audio/video format (MP3 by default) to any other format (WAV by default).
# Input to function either "bytes" data or "str" path or read-opened "file" object.
# "ifmt" is input format (taken from input path by default or MP3 if not provided)
# "ofmt" is output format, WAV by default
# "ffmpeg" should contain path to ffmpeg executable
# Function returns converted audio bytes.
def conv_aud(data, ifmt = None, ofmt = 'wav', *, ffmpeg = 'ffmpeg'):
    import tempfile, subprocess, secrets, traceback
    inp_path = None
    if type(data) is str:
        inp_path, data = data, None
    elif type(data) is not bytes:
        data = data.read()
    assert inp_path is not None or type(data) is bytes, (inp_path, type(data))
    if inp_path is not None:
        ifmt_ = inp_path[inp_path.rfind('.') + 1:].lower()
        assert ifmt is None or ifmt.lower() == ifmt_, (ifmt, ifmt_)
        ifmt = ifmt_
    elif ifmt is None:
        ifmt = 'mp3'
    assert ifmt is not None and ofmt is not None, (ifmt, ofmt)
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td:
        if data is not None:
            inp_path = str(td) + '/' + secrets.token_hex(8).upper() + '.' + ifmt.lower()
            with open(inp_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(data)
        out_path = str(td) + '/' + secrets.token_hex(8).upper() + '.' + ofmt.lower()
        try:
            with open(str(td) + '/out', 'wb') as fout, open(str(td) + '/err', 'wb') as ferr:
                subprocess.run([ffmpeg, '-i', inp_path, out_path], check = True, stdout = fout, stderr = ferr)
            good = True
        except:
            with open(str(td) + '/out', 'rb') as fout, open(str(td) + '/err', 'rb') as ferr:
                for f, n in [(fout, ' stdout '), (ferr, ' stderr ')]:
                    print('-' * 20 + n + '-' * 20 + '\n', f.read().decode('utf-8', 'replace'), sep = '', end = '')
            print('-' * 50)
            good = False
        if not good:
            assert False, 'FFMpeg returned error!'
        with open(out_path, 'rb') as f:
            return f.read()
            
# Testing conv_aud
def test():
    for inp in [open('test.mp3', 'rb').read(), 'test.mp3', open('test.mp3', 'rb')]:
        print(conv_aud(inp)[:32].hex().upper())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Output for my `test.mp3` file:

```
5249464654D0110357415645666D7420100000000100020044AC000010B10200
5249464654D0110357415645666D7420100000000100020044AC000010B10200
5249464654D0110357415645666D7420100000000100020044AC000010B10200
```

Comment: I want to get  the solution for this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640560/how-to-define-fast-forward-button-in-pygame-using-python

Sir, I have tried it but it doesn't work

If it's not working then I have no problem I want only to make only fast forward button for my music player

I will very glad if you solve my problem

Comment: @SDBDARKNINJA OK, I'll try to solve that other your question now, I'll reply there.

Comment: @SDBDARKNINJA I solved you second task, [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64647710/941531).

Comment: Thank you sir I will try it and inform you